# Python : Unable to set root server as name server

Tags: python, dns, resolver

```
import dns.resolver

myresolver = dns.resolver.Resolver() 
myresolver.nameservers=['192.203.230.10']
ipaddress = myresolver.query('www.google.com')
```

The above code gives me "NoAnswer" Error. If I set the name server to `8.8.8.8`, it works perfectly. How can i direct my query to the root server mentioned by using `dns.resolver`?

Comment: The access to root server is not blocked. i am able to query to it through dig

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your query to `e.root-servers.net.`. What's wrong is your expectation that said root server would give you an answer for `www.google.com`. If you were to look more closely at the response you get, you would see that it holds a referral to `.com`.